# Comparing multiple models with something like a Diebold-Mariano test

Tags: forecasting, multiple-comparisons, model-comparison, diebold-mariano-test

I run many models on different samples (i.e., datasets which are slightly different from each other).

I calculate the MSE for each model on these datasets. Now I want to compare these models to see if there is a significant difference between their performance.

I decided to use Diebold-Mariano test as it can deal with dependent datasets. How can I choose the p-value as I have many tests? Should I compare model 1 to model 2 or model 1 with all models?

Comment: In what sense can the DM test deal with dependent datasets? You would need to account for the dependence explicitly, and that may be nontrivial. In which sense are the datasets slightly different from each other? For some potentially relevant tests for multiple models, consult the tag description for [`diebold-mariano-test`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/diebold-mariano-test/info).

Answer (score 0):

The Diebold Mariano test is a pairwise test, for comparing model forecasts, and not the models themselves. See Diebold's 2012 paper: http://www.nber.org/papers/w18391

Therefore, one approach would be to set the forecast with the lowest MSE as the benchmark and then compare each of the other sets of forecasts to the benchmark forecast to determine whether the benchmark forecast is significantly different to the other forecasts.

Another approach would be to use the Model Confidence Set (MCS) approach in which a subset of models is identified which contains the best models with a given confidence level, see Hansen et al. (2005): https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/100950/1/wp2005-07.pdf.

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph, how do you suggest to implement the comparison? A test like the Diebold-Mariano test only works when the pair of competing forecasts is selected ex ante. If they are selected ex post based on their performance, the winner's curse makes comparisons very difficult. Namely, the performance of the ex-post best model will be overestimated, and adjusting for that in a test is hard. Without an adjustment, you will get nonsense results. On the other hand, your suggestion regarding MCS is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Richard Hardy. If you have only two competing models, you would select the best using MSE and then use the DM test to check statistical significance as you explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253314/diebold-mariano-but-how-to-say-which-one-is-more-accurate?rq=1). Now if you have three competing models then you select the one with the lowest MSE, and then check it against the other two models in turn for statistical significance, or is my reasoning mistaken here?

Comment: Already with 3 models, the results will be biased because of the winner's curse. The more models under consideration, the greater the bias.